# Issue with sharing a variable across mulitple process in python via joblib

Tags: python-3.x

Is sharing a file with size 500KB from main process to sub processes will be more expensive than loading the same file via I/O loading in sub-process when  multiprocessing implemented via Joblib(loky) in python?